# How to Make a Math Symbol in Word

Tags: notation

I have a student typing up her thesis.  She needs to type external tensor, $\boxtimes$.  Is there anyway to get that symbol in Microsoft Word?  She doesn't know how to use TeX.

Comment: I added the tag 'notation' because I couldn't think of a more appropriate tag.

Comment: Has she tried copying and pasting it from your question?  Works for me on just about every editor i use (don't have Word specifically)

Comment: copy-paste the symbol from your post gives me this : ⊠ what about in word ?

Comment: She should learn TeX. She's typing up a mathematical paper in Word?

Comment: Maybe you should try using TeX to Word converter.

Comment: @noobProgrammer In her defense, she is an undergraduate student.  Grad school will force her to use TeX.  Although, I did know someone who used Word for their Ph.D. once (ugh!).

Comment: @muzzlator I will ask her to try that.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: Make a new sheet and click Alt and + at the same time to make a box for typing an equation. Then tell her to go to Equation tools (Design) and the part Operators. I see the symbol you wanted there right now.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I know of Math grad students who do not know Latex, and was horrified. I'd think of it as an indicator that their quality of work is low. Then again, I'm sure we all know of an (old) prof who doesn't know latex.

Comment: I'm not trying to advertise anything, but I _am_ teaching [this](http://www.pcc.edu/ccog/default.cfm?fa=ccog&subject=MTH&course=84) as an online course that starts next week. (The description in the link is a little outdated - a more up-to-date list of topics would be something like: installation, mathematical and scientific content, formatting, tables, figures including basics of pgfplots, multichapter documents, and beamer.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about Mathematics. For question on how to use Microsoft Word, http://superuser.com is a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem that Word will render the symbol by "copy and paste". It worked in implementation of Word (Office 10), and rendered as Cambria Math (font), with size $13$, which can be scaled to a different font size.

**Edit:** the symbol "$\boxtimes$" can be *directly inserted from/within "Word"* using:

- "insert":

  - "symbol": < choose "normal text": "mathematical operators">.

Or, the better option if working within the Word "Equation Editor" environment:

- "insert"

  - "Equation": "math operators": < See "special operators">

The symbol in Word is referred to as "squared times."

It rendered as the exact image compared to "copied-and-pasted" symbol I inserted.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to tell the OP it is called "squared times". Thanks for remarking that.

Comment: My student went with your answer.  So, I'll give you the check.

Comment: @amWhy: I recall there was a Scientific Word that included a CAS with it. I wish someone would make such a nicely integrated tool! Perhaps people are catching up with things like LibreOffice. +1

Comment: Is LibreOffice OpenOffice? or has the name changed?

Answer (score 3):

Do as I suggested you above. I made a photo showing that.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: How do you take a "screen shot"?

Comment: @amWhy: PrintScreen + Ctrl-V into a photo editor (e.g. MS Paint)

Comment: @AsafKaragila PrintScreen grabs the *entire* screen. Usually you ust want a picture of a single application window. For that, one can use Alt+PrintScreen.

Comment: Thanks, @Asaf! I've done this before (for programming), but it's been awhile, and I went "blank"!!

Comment: @kahen: That can be later cut in the editor; if you want to get clever, click on the menu arrow in E17 and select the option to take a snapshot of the window. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: I did exactly what Asaf noted.

Comment: @amWhy:for "screen shot" (part of screen)open onenote(This is one of the microsoft Office programs)and Press the Windows key+s and choose where you want to shoot and Ctrl+V into a photo editor.;)

Comment: Thanks, @flashdesign2550 ! $\Large\ddot\smile$

Comment: @amWhy:.•*.`,+.*`.*•.█▓░you are welcome░▓█.•*.`,+.*`.*•.